# How to create a variable only once when app is created in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am creating an android application. In my application, I need a variable that initializes only once when the application is first created. It should not be initialized even when the app gets updated. I added, "entered". So whenever I open the app I should have `ArrayList` which contains `entered` String.

```
ArrayList<String> strings=new ArrayList<String>();
strings.add("entered");
```

Comment: Shared Preferences.

Comment: read about something like "constructor"

Comment: @Brarord `It should not be initilalised even when app gets updated.`. i doubt a constructor will help for this, unless you want to clarify :)

Answer (score 8):

As @blackapps mentioned You can use [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences)

In MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

    String yourVariable = sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.nameOfValue), getString(R.string.defaultValue));

    if (yourVariable.equals(getString(R.string.defaultValue))) //app was run for 1st time
    {
        editor.putString(getString(R.string.nameOfValue), "String which You want to save"); //value that You want to put
        editor.apply();
    }
    else
    {
        // app wasn't run for 1st time
    }
}
```

In string.xml

```
<string name="nameOfValue">NAME_OF_VALUE</string>
<string name="defaultValue">DEFAULT_VALUE</string>
```

I saved `String` but You can save any type in Shared Preferences.

---

**Edit:**
To save ArrayList You can use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)

First add dependency to grade and sync project:

```
implementstion 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```

And then use this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

        boolean firstRun = sharedPref.getBoolean(getString(R.string.firstRun), true);
        ArrayList<String> arrayList;
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        if (firstRun) //app was run for 1st time
        {
            System.out.println("First run");

            // initialize array as You want
            arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            arrayList.add("Some string");
            String arrayJSON = gson.toJson(arrayList);

            // add values to SharedPreferences
            editor.putString(getString(R.string.nameOfValue), arrayJSON);
            editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.firstRun), false);

            // apply changes
            editor.apply();
        }
        else // app wasn't run for 1st time
        {
            System.out.println("Not first run");

            String arrayJSON = sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.nameOfValue), getString(R.string.defaultValue));
            arrayList = gson.fromJson(arrayJSON, new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>()
            {
            }.getType());
        }

        for (String s : arrayList)
        {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to initialize ArrayList<String> How can i do that? @iknow

Comment: i definitely wouldn't use string resources for getting constants out of shared prefs, personally i'd use static variables, i just don't agree with that usage for `strings.xml`, however, i agree with your answer :)

Comment: @Rocky If You want to save array use GSON [this video probably help You](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jcliHGR3CHo)

Comment: @a_local_nobody I don't know if it is the best way to use `strings.xml` but in docs is a similar example so I do it in this way. Maybe You are right that `const` variables are better

Comment: @Rocky After You edited Your question I edited my answer, now You can save array of string as You want.